# How to change the color of line plotted on y axis midway in plotly?

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly

I have a dataframe with 2 columns: 'Ground Truth' and 'Predicted Values', that I am plotting using plotly express.

```
timestamp                Ground Truth     Predicted Values
2012-04-01 00:30:00      251.71               NA
2012-04-01 00:15:00      652.782              NA
2012-04-01 00:00:00      458.099              NA
2012-03-31 23:45:00      3504.664             NA
2012-03-31 23:30:00      1215.76             1230
2012-03-31 23:15:00     -21.48               -19.99
2012-03-31 23:00:00     -8.538               -7.42
2012-03-31 22:40:00     -5.11                -5.2
```

Code for plot

```
fig = px.line(df, x = df.index, y = ['Ground Truth','Predicted Values'], markers='.')   
    
fig.update_xaxes(
        rangeslider_visible=True,
        rangeselector=dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(count = 1, label = "1H", step = "hour", stepmode ="backward"),
                dict(step="all")
            ])
        )
    )
fig.show()
```

With the current code, one line for each column is being plotted (As per given below). I am trying to change the graph, in which the blue line's changes to some other color from the start of the red line. Can someone please help? (In reference to the dataframe, the red line is for 'Predicted values' columns which starts after the NA values end).

Current graph (plotted on different values):
[image]

Comment: To make it easy, copy the data from the date you want to change the color and create a new column. Days with no data in the new column are assumed to be NA. Then add the new column name to the specified column on the y-axis.　`fig = px.line(df, x = df.index, y = ['Ground Truth','Predicted Values','Ground Truth2'], markers='.')`

Comment: Thanks but in that case, I would have to create a new column based on the condition that the new column is populated with values from 'Ground Truth', only from index where 'Predicted values' have values. I do not want to hard code the date. Could you help with that?

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to code dates separately. Another way is to add a column of the desired color in the graph object and specify the color of the marker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it based on the help from @r-beginners comment above. I'll add the code here, in case it might help anyone.

Use boolean indexing. I create a new column in the DataFrame called 'New Column' and fill it with NaN values. Then used boolean indexing to set the values in 'New Column' where 'Predicted Values' are not NaN to the corresponding values in 'Ground Truth'. The ~ operator inverts the boolean mask generated by the isna() method, so I am selecting rows where 'Predicted Values' are not NaN.

```
# Create a new column and populate it with 'Ground Truth' values where 'Predicted Values' are not NaN
df['New Column'] = np.nan
df.loc[~df['Predicted Values'].isna(), 'New Column'] = df.loc[~df['Predicted Values'].isna(), 'Ground Truth']
```